# Has roxterm been removed from Debian 9 (stretch)?

Tags: debian

I just installed Debian 9 this morning to test before upgrading. My preferred terminal app is "roxterm", and it is one of the first things I always install.

Ran "sudo apt update" (no errors), then "sudo apt install roxterm" and got the following:

```
E: Unable to locate package roxterm
```

I've been looking up Debian 9 & roxterm off and on all day today and haven't found any inkling as to whether or not it has been removed, and if it hasn't, why I can't find it.

Here's my sources.list:

```
# deb http://debian.uchicago.edu/debian/ stretch main

deb http://debian.uchicago.edu/debian/ stretch main
deb-src http://debian.uchicago.edu/debian/ stretch main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://debian.uchicago.edu/debian/ stretch-updates main
deb-src http://debian.uchicago.edu/debian/ stretch-updates main

# add contrib & non-free repos
#deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch contrib non-free
#deb http://security.debian.org stretch/updates contrib non-free
deb http://debian.uchicago.edu/debian stretch contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates contrib non-free
```

I've also run "sudo apt-cache search roxterm" - nothing shows up.

No issues installing a number of other packages...

Any information on either what I'm missing or where I should look would be much appreciated!

*Edited to add* - also tried "apt-get" in place of "apt" a few times even though it isn't needed any longer, as well as su'ing to root and running the commands w/out "sudo" - all with the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a package isn't available from your package sources, you won't find any information through local means. You can get information about the fate of a package in Debian on the website: [`https://packages.debian.org/package-name`](https://bugs.debian.org/roxterm), [`https://bugs.debian.org/package-name`](https://bugs.debian.org/roxterm), [`https://packages.qa.debian.org/First letter of name/package-name`](https://packages.qa.debian.org/r/roxterm.html).

[On the [package page](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/roxterm), you can see that `roxterm` is present in wheezy and jessie, but not in buster and it isn't in unstable anymore either. There's also a link to the QA page.

On the [QA page](https://packages.qa.debian.org/r/roxterm.html), you'll find information about why a package has been automatically removed from testing and how a package might be removed from Debian altogether..

Roxterm was [removed from unstable in June 2016](https://packages.qa.debian.org/r/roxterm/news/20160621T054501Z.html) for the reason

> ROM¹; Upstream discontinued; has RC bug

Unless you want to take on the maintenance of roxterm, you'd better find an alternative.

The details are in [Bug #827768](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=827768).

¹  <sub>[Request of Maintainer](https://wiki.debian.org/Glossary#R).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Debian package tracker](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/roxterm), it was removed from testing a year ago, and is present only in wheezy and jessie.